# Arrays.sort(), how to compare to long values?

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

I have an Array with 100 objects in it, every object has a long value.
I can get the long value by `object.getlongValue()`.
How do I use Comparable to compare those two values?
What I did:

```java
public class objects implements Comparable<objects>{

private long longValue;

public object(long longValue){
this.longValue = longValue;
}

public long getLongValue(){
return longValue;
}

@Override
    public int compareTo(object obj) {
        return this.compareTo(obj.getLongValue); //now he can't find compareTo
    }
```

And later in when I need to sort the Array, I do the following:

```java
Arrays.sort(ListOfObj, new Comparator<objects>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(objects obj, objects obj1) {
                    return obj.getLongValue().compareTo(obj1.getLongValue());
                 // Here he dosen't know "compareTo" either
                }
            });
```

Of cause this is NOT the real Object class, this is just for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` is primitive in Java and has no `compareTo` method. But, you can box it to `Long`:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(object obj) 
        return new Long(this.getLongValue()).compareTo(new Long(obj.getLongValue()));
    }
```

or just use `signum` function:

```
 Long.signum(this.getLongValue() - obj.getLongValue());
```